# Iterate to next prerequisite file when matching when given variables for statement

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to do something like this with make:

```
SRC := $(src/*.md)
DIST := $(subst -,/,$(patsubst src/%.md, dist/%/index.html, $(SRC)))

all: $(DIST)

$(DIST): $(SRC)
  mkdir -p $(@D) && pandoc $< -o $@
```

E.g., the prerequisite `src/2014-04-myfile.md` is put into target `dist/2014/04/myfile/index.html` with the transform `pandoc`

But when I use `$<` it only refers to the first argument in the `$(SRC)` variable.

I know normally we would do something like:

```
dist/%.html: src/%.md
```

but since I changed the file name in the output to just `index.html` for all files and used the original file name to create a new path I'm not sure how to go about iterating over the prerequisites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way it could be done. The way this works is that it iterates over `$(SRC)` to create one rule per source file. The `$$` in `MAKE_DEP` are necessary to prevent `make` from interpreting the functions when it first reads the contents of `MAKE_DEP`. The documentation on [`call`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html) and [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html#Eval-Function) are also useful.

```
SRC := $(wildcard src/*.md)

# Set the default goal if no goal has been specified...
.DEFAULT_GOAL:=all

#
# This is a macro that we use to create the rules.
#
define MAKE_DEP
# _target is a temporary "internal" variable used to avoid recomputing
# the current target multiple times.
_target:=$$(subst -,/,$$(patsubst src/%.md, dist/%/index.html, $1))

# Add the current target to the list of targets.
TARGETS:=$$(TARGETS) $$(_target)

# Create the rule proper.
$$(_target):$1
    mkdir -p $$(@D) && pandoc $$< -o $$@

endef # MAKE_DEP

# Iterate over $(SRC) to create each rule.
$(foreach x,$(SRC),$(eval $(call MAKE_DEP,$x)))

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGETS)
```

If I create:

```
src/2000-01-bar.md
src/2014-04-foo.md
```

and run `$ make -n`, I get:

```
mkdir -p dist/2000/01/bar && pandoc src/2000-01-bar.md -o dist/2000/01/bar/index.html
mkdir -p dist/2014/04/foo && pandoc src/2014-04-foo.md -o dist/2014/04/foo/index.html
```

This could also be done using [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) but it did not appear to me to be simpler or nicer.